# Collect a single variable in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = [ "test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

I would like to assign the variables in the list as a string to x, and every new variable will be put together, but not put at the end.
I would like `"test, test2, test3"`

What should I do for this?

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify this a bit. You don't have variables, you have a list of strings. It looks like you want to `join()` them but I don't understand "but not put at the end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` like this to get desired result if all the list items are `str`

```
data = [ "test1", "test2", "test3"]

print(', '.join(data)) # Output : test1, test2, test3
```

Also, keep in mind it is not a good practice to use Python keywords as variable names.

If you want to do the same with a list of other data items that are not string you can use `map` over the list followed by `join` like shown below.

```
data = [ "test1", "test2", "test3"]

print(', '.join(map(str, data))) # Output : test1, test2, test3
```

Alternatively, if you are not comfortable in using `map`, you can use a list comprehension inside join like this

```
data = [ "test1", "test2", "test3"]

print(', '.join(str(x) for x in data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. Just add all the strings in the list. Also avoid using variables names which are keywords like `list`.

```
output= ""
for item in myList:
    if output == "":
        output += item
    else:
        output  += ', '
        output += item

print(str)
```

Comment: What's wrong about good ol' `', '.join(L)`?

Comment: I like your tip of not using keywords as variable names (such as `list`), which is also why I would refrain from using `str` as a variable name

Comment: @bereal, thats indeed shorter and good!  this is what OP want to achieve based on answers are given :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake @Jondiedoop.